Fragments with Kotlin
package com.fungus.app;

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView


class FragmentFirst : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var autoCompleteTextView: MaterialAutoCompleteTextView

    private var _binding: FragmentFirstBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

            override fun onCreateView(
                inflater: LayoutInflater,
                container: ViewGroup?,
                savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

            _binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
            val view = binding.root

            autoCompleteTextView = binding.autocompleteTextView

            val colour = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Colours)
            val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(requireContext(), R.layout.dropdown_item, colour!!)
            autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter)

    return view
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}

I am very new to Fragments in Kotlin and i just wanted to try and use one to make my dropdown menus look a little better, I have an xml file called fragment_first.xml and the Kotlin class called FragmentFirst and the error i get is that "FragmentFirstBinding" is an unresolved reference, i truly dont understand the error and to my understanding it should work, so i humbly ask what i understood wrong or didnt understand at all, Thank you

It should be FirstFragmentBinding, not FragmentFirstBinding. But your first question is confusing. Make the drop-down look better as compared to what? A Fragment is a way of organizing the way your UI code works, not a way to “make it look better”.

why should it be FirstFragmentBinding ? and look better compared to using regular spinner based drop down menus, it is however not the most important thing, for me its more important to understand how Fragments work. (changing it to FirstFragmentBinding doesnt solve the problem)

It takes the words from the xml file’s name, changes them to camel case, removes underscores, and adds the word Binding. So the order of the words should not have been swapped like you had them. A Fragment hosts a piece of UI—it doesn’t affect how the UI actually looks. Your spinner won’t look different if you put it in a Fragment instead of directly in an Activity.

I am terrebly sorry i missnamed the xml file, of course it is called fragment_first.xml, and thank you for the information about what fragments are, i did know most of that but some aspacts were very helpful. and i do understand that the spinner wont look any different, Thanks

Maybe you missed the step to enable view binding in your gradle configuration.
